# How to create a link and anchor using platypus and ReportLab Pdf python

Tags: python, hyperlink, reportlab, clickable, platypus

This is what the platypus documentation states:

***The link tag can be used as a reference, but not as an anchor. The a and link hyperlink tags have additional attributes fontName, fontSize, color & backColor attributes. The hyperlink reference can have a scheme of
http:(external webpage), pdf:(different pdf document) or document:(same pdf document); a missing scheme
is treated as document as is the case when the reference starts with # (in which case the anchor should omit
it). Any other scheme is treated as some kind of URI.***

I want to create a clickable link that takes you to another page in the same pdf but im not sure how to create the "anchor", if anyone understands please can you help! (I am obviously not using a canvas)
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. You could find a bunch of tutorial on the net. And in case you are facing specific issue with your code, you could please specific question to your issue here. But if you are expecting someone would coding for you, I guess your wrong here. Please consider to check [example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Just copy and paste code to test.

```
from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph, PageBreak, SimpleDocTemplate
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet

pdf = SimpleDocTemplate('PDFname.pdf')
story = []
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
story.append(Paragraph('This <a href="#MYANCHOR" color="blue">is a link to</a>', style=styles["Normal"])) # Linking the anchor
story.append(PageBreak())
story.append(Paragraph('<a name="MYANCHOR"/><font color="green">here</font>', style=styles["Normal"])) # Creating anchor
pdf.build(story)
```